# How do I run one docker container from another at regular intervals?

Tags: docker, http, networking, devops, vapor

I have a Vapor server application running on a Docker container. I have another Docker container that runs a python web-scraping script which outputs a json file to a volume that will then be accessed by the Vapor app. The former will be "always on", the latter will run its script and then exit.

I understand I can use Docker-Compose in my Vapor app to spin this second Docker container up to run the python script when I launch my Vapor app... but what if I want to do it, say, once an hour, or every 10 minutes? I do not want to run Docker in Docker since that's insecure for eventual cloud deployment.

Does this require configuring an HTTP API? If so, how does that communicate with the Docker network?

Comment: If security is a concern, one container launching another will always be a problem.  (If you can launch a container, then you can be root inside the new container, and you can mount arbitrary parts of the host filesystem into the new container, so you can very easily root the host.)  A second long-running worker process, fed via either an HTTP interface or a task queue like RabbitMQ, would be easier to maintain, wouldn't be directly tied to Docker, and wouldn't have these security considerations.

Comment: @DavidMaze so the "worker process" is code in my server app that makes an HTTP call to my second docker container, telling it to spin up and run its script?

Comment: You have two containers; both are always running.  When a job needs to be done, one makes an HTTP call to the other to tell it to do its work.  Or, you have those two containers, plus a third running a job queue; the containers don't directly communicate, but the first puts a job in the queue that the second consumes.  Nothing "spins up", and you don't need access to the Docker API.

Comment: Ok thanks. My research tells me the second option might be best for me: create a `cron` container which is just a scheduler, telling the other container to run its script and then remove it at whatever interval. It's then decoupled from my server application, which can call the database according to its own scheduling logic.

Answer (score 1):

add this line in your compose file :
restart: on-failure
this witll restart your service in every fail it found
and for intervall you can user healthcheck

example of code ;

```
version: "3.4"
```

services:
apigateway:
image: apigateway.jar
build:
context: ../waw/gateways
dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
ports:
- 8444:8444
networks:
- backend
restart: on-failure
healthcheck:
test: [ "CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:8444" ]
interval: 1m30s
timeout: 10s
retries: 5